# Данные с другой страницы

Tags: php

Необходимо сделать при помощи PHP следующее: эта вещь, я так понимаю, называется бот. У меня есть адрес сайта, бот должен на этом сайте в поле, там, к примеру, `input type="text"`, писать какое-то слово, нажимать на кнопку поиск (которая рядом), и получившиеся результаты закидывать в базу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать либо это узнать, ну или натолкните на мысли, как сделать, исходники не обязательны.

Comment: Если надо именно нажать - бот не умеет имитировать нажатие, если там, например ajax поиск - вам надо рзобраться что и на какой URL отправляется и что приходит, и потом, просто отправлять туда интересующий вас запрос.<br>
Если же это `input type="submit"` - curl, тривиальный код, PROFIT

Comment: Сайт ещё для выполнения действий требует регистрацию..

Comment: Почитайте про curl или есть класс HTTP_REQUEST. Они позволяют иммитировать формы и посылать данные на стороне сервера методами GET и POST и получать результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это не должно происходить автоматически, то вполне можно воспользоваться [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) - макрос для тестирования, в котором можно записать все свои действия один раз и повторять их сколько и когда потребуется.

Если же вы хотите это все сделать средствами программирования, то совсем не обязательно заполнять форму, формируйте POST и отправляйте сразу на тот скрипт, который должен обрабатывать запрос, для этого вполне подойдет [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), при помощи которого достаточно просто отправлять данные и получать ответы с которыми потом уже делать то что вам нужно. Туториалы по нему можно без труда найти в сети.

Comment: про curl почитаем, а что по поводу обхода регистрации?

Comment: А зачем ее обходить то?<br>
Логинетесь curl'ом и дальше уже делаете свои "грязные" дела :)<br><br>
Если там есть что-то типа "запомнить меня"( а скорее всего такое есть ), вообще просто. Регаетесь, логинетесь, жмете "запомнить меня". Смотрите куку, curl'ом передаете необходимые данные в заголовке, PROFIT

Comment: в CURL вы можете установить значения для полей, их название можно посмотреть в коде HTML странички, допустим поле <input type='text' name='login' /> соответственно и скрипт который читает данные формы на сайте ожидает увидеть это значение в $_POST['login'], т.е. идея в том что CURL умеет сам формировать массив $_POST, вы для этого передаете параметры, далее CURL передает эти параметры, сам скрипт на сайте думает что это форма ему их передала. Посмотрите пару туториалов не сильно заморачиваясь на параметрах CURL и идею вы поймете быстро